# NativeScript + Angular - New project Error on Preview: Type AppRoutingModule does not have 'ngModuleDef' property

Tags: angular, nativescript, preview, generated

I installed everything need. The project is the generated one. I don't even have made changes but when I try to preview it and scan the qrcode, I got an Error "Type AppRoutingModule does not have 'ngModuleDef' property".

- npm 6.14.6
- nodejs LTS v12.18.3
- Angular cli 10.1.1 which I use to run an angular project
- NativeScript CLI v7.0.7

I always end up having this error:

````
Error: Type AppRoutingModule does not have 'ngModuleDef' property.
File: (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1682:12)
StackTrace: 
ZoneAwareError(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:1298:33)
    at getNgModuleDef(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1682:19)
    at (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1513:31)
    at noSideEffects(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1321:19)
    at ����setNgModuleScope(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1512:16)
    at (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/bundle.js:49:131)
    at ./app/app-routing.module.ts(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/bundle.js:49:339)
    at __webpack_require__(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/runtime.js:817:30)
    at fn(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
    at ./app/app.module.ts(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/bundle.js:103:77)
    at __webpack_require__(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/runtime.js:817:30)
    at fn(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/runtime.js:121:20)
    at (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/bundle.js:306:73)
    at ./main.ts(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/bundle.js:372:30)
    at __webpack_require__(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/runtime.js:817:30)
    at checkDeferredModules(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/runtime.js:44:23)
    at webpackJsonpCallback(file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/runtime.js:31:19)
    at (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/bundle.js:2:57)
    at require(:1:266)

Error: Type AppRoutingModule does not have 'ngModuleDef' property.
    at com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method)
    at com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:674)
    at com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:666)
    at com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:21)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1155)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5949)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:200)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1673)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)```

Thank you for your help!
````

Comment: it's a known issue with ANgular 10 on the NativeScript project : https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-schematics/issues/290

Answer (score 0):

That works for me:

1. Run the advanced setup. [Full setup](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/start/quick-setup.html#full-setup)
2. run *tns doctor* if all green go to next step.
3. Plug in mobile device.
4. run *ns run android*

Let the magic happen

[GitHub solution](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-schematics/issues/290#issuecomment-781137564)

Answer (score 0):

First I did [full setup](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/start/quick-setup.html#full-setup) then I uninstalled JDK 18 and then `ns run android` worked.